# Facebook deeplinks tumblr app for my blog links on mobile

Tags: ios, facebook, tumblr, deep-linking, deeplink

Very weird and annoying situation!
When clicking on the links of tumblr blog with custom domain in facebook app, instead of opening the url facebook offers tumblr app.

I believe facebook requests my url, understands it is tumblr and deeplinks its app instead of going to my blog url. Is it a server side problem from Tumblr or facebook issue?

Is there a way to cancel the deeplinking for the blog?

**Steps to reproduce**: Share the link on facebook. click on it using ios facebook app. Instead of opening the link, it opens the store link for tumblr app or opens tumblr app if it is already installed.
**Exceptions**: behavior is normal when the link is shared using a shortener service.

Comment: I haven't seen this before. Mind editing your question to include the specific link you're using, and the steps to reproduce?

Comment: Yep, sure. When using any link at http://elawphant.am, e.g. http://elawphant.am/post/154805765686/3-թույլտվություն-որ-անհրաժեշտ-է-երևանում. If you post the link on facebook and than click on it in facebook iOS app (I am not sure whether this happens on androids, too), instead of opening the link it offers tumblr app.

Comment: Also, when I post the link using a shortener service like ow.ly, or bit.ly or smth else, it just works fine, it does not offer tumblr app. So the problem happens on direct links.